# mycnf under etc does not take effect

Tags: mysql, my.cnf

1. Install mysql offline.
2. Create /etc/my.cnf file manually.
3. Add some options in /etc/my.cnf.
4. Restart MySQL.
5. Login MySQL, options added does not take effect.
6. /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf is ok.

OS: Ubuntu 18.04, Ubuntu 20.04
MySQL: 8.0.27

1. There is no specified .cnf file.
2. [mysqld --verbose --help | grep -A 1 'Default options'] result is ok.
   `Default options are read from the following files in the given order: /etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf`
3. /etc/my.cnf should be ok, but it's not.

Comment: Can you share more info on ("/etc/my.cnf should be ok, but it's not") Does this file exist? What is the content of this file?

Comment: should be ok, but it's not - what is not okay? Did you check with SQL Command SHOW Variables; if changes from my.cnf are used or not?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: File “/etc/my.cnf” exists. Any option in this file takes no effect. For example, add "max_connections=1000" in “/etc/my.cnf”, then restart MySQL, login MySQL and use "select @@max_connections" to check, the value of "max_connections" is still the default value(151). I have tried many options and the result is the same.